# Issue with getting Groups conversation

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api

I am currently playing with Microsoft Graph Api for groups. When I access the group conversations(https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/3b41ffb2-4fec-4ca6-97f8-40c70eb75df3/conversations) through API Explorer(https://graphexplorer2.azurewebsites.net), it works fine. But if I access the same through Postman I receive the below error.

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "ErrorInternalServerError",
    "message": "The SMTP address has no mailbox associated with it.",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "20289ba7-0782-4d0e-9ea9-64e4567bfca6",
      "date": "2016-01-13T13:05:21"
    }
  }
}
```

But in Postman below APIs are working fine.

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/3b41ffb2-4fec-4ca6-97f8-40c70eb75df3

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups

In the Azure AD application created for testing purpose, I have also enabled all the permissions for Graph API and Azure AD rights. I am unable to proceed further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Group conversation access is not supported in app-only authorization flow.

We are working on returning a better error for this case.

Comment: Hi @Marek Rycharski, I'm currently trying practically the same as the OP, but instead the error is: "message": "Access is denied. Check credentials and try again.". Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Just a reminder that my AD application has all the permissions. In a desperate mode, I've enabled all permissions to the "other applications".

Comment: Hi @AuroMetal, could you please provide the request-id and timestamp of your request?

Comment: Hi @Marek Rycharski, thanks very much for your reply. Once again I just would like to enfasize that the same request works perfectly fine in Fiddler, but not through [https://graphexplorer2.azurewebsites.net/](https://graphexplorer2.azurewebsites.net/). The request-id is: **e25e2d03-96d8-4242-8bad-3f9be16f0a6c** and the timestamp is: **2016-02-18T08:49:16**. If I try https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me, for instance, that works good on both.

Comment: @AuroMetal - your request was sent with an app+user access token for which access to group conversations is supported, so it's a different scenario. 403/Forbidden was returned for this request because the access token didn't have the required Group scopes. Could you sign in as admin tenant to the Azure management portal (https://manage.windowsazure.com) and remove access for the Graph Explorer application? Then sign in to https://graphexplorer2.azurewebsites.net/ and you should be asked to consent to group permissions, which should make that request work for you via the Graph Explorer app.

Answer (score 0):

You can track the HTTP request via the fiddler to see the difference between Microsoft Graph and Postman. We can also get the access token via track the HTTP request and construct the request with Fiddler.
Hope it is helpful.