# Microsoft Graph API : "403 forbidden" error when getting groups conversations

Tags: office365, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

In a **Node.js** script using [adal-node](https://www.npmjs.com/package/adal-node), I'm trying to retrieve a group conversations following parts of [this official documentation](https://dev.office.com/blogs/GroupsRESTAPI).

I've created an application in **Azure AD administration** for my tenant, and temporarily checked all permissions for **Graph API** (should exclude a "missing permission" problem), then clicked on the "**Grant permissions**" button.

I'm using a certificate for authentication.

Basically I'm doing:

```
var adal = require('adal-node');
var authorityUrl = 'https://login.windows.net/{my-tenant}';
var context = new adal.AuthenticationContext(authorityUrl);
context.acquireTokenWithClientCertificate(
    'https://graph.microsoft.com',
    '{my-app/client-ID}',
    '{certificate file content}',
    '{certificate thumbprint}',
    function(err, tokenResponse) {
        // this method does an HTTPS call with autorization token & returns results (uses 'https.request()')
        callRestApi(
            'graph.microsoft.com', // host
            443, // port
            '/v1.0/groups/{group-ID}/threads', // path
            'GET', // method
            tokenResponse.accessToken, // token
            function(err, results) {
                console.log(err);
                console.log(results);
            });
    });
```

When I'm using, for example, `/v1.0/groups/{group-ID}/description` as path, it works as expected.

However, with `/v1.0/groups/{group-ID}/conversations` or `/v1.0/groups/{group-ID}/threads`, I always get an **HTTP 403 / Forbidden** error (without any further detail in response.headers).

Note that when I try to do the same exact call from the [online Graph API Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer) with my tenant admin account, it works as expected.

Comment: Maybe related? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34767672/issue-with-getting-groups-conversation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK ,as @Marek Rycharski said in the thread , group conversation access is not supported in app-only authorization flow.

In my testing , i used client credential flow to acquire app-only token for microsoft graph, the difference is my client credential is a password , and the access token includes `Group.ReadWrite.All` application permission, when performing  `/v1.0/groups/{group-ID}/conversations` operation , the response shows 403 Forbidden error . But using authorization code flow to acquire access token with delegate permission , the list conversations operation works fine .