# Reading Group Conversations from Microsoft Graph using an application permission doesn't seem to be supported

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

We're building a mashup app that allows you to view data and information from multiple sources in one place.

To do this we need to get all conversations in O365 Groups and have been exploring how to build a daemon job.

According to the documentation this should be supported since we have the permissions `Group.Read.All` and `Group.ReadWrite.All`.

[image: Permissions in groups]

However it seems like Groups Conversations is an exception to what you can read with an application permission with Microsoft Graph which is mentioned in a small note on the [subscriptions page](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/subscription_post_subscriptions):

[image: Note about permissions]

We get permissions errors when calling the API with a application permission using a certificate (fetching groups and other data works fine) so this seems to be a limitation.

This also seems to affect fetching threads which doesn't seem to have any notes regarding application permissions at all since we can't fetch those either.

Does anybody know if there is a workaround or if we're doing something wrong here?

(NOTE: This seems to be a related question: [Microsoft Graph API : "403 forbidden" error when getting groups conversations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45673636/microsoft-graph-api-403-forbidden-error-when-getting-groups-conversations) but I'd like to have some input from Microsoft on this)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft confirmed this as being an issue in the Microsoft Graph through our partner programme.

Until fixed by Microsoft this means that there is no good solution except workarounds as of now.